# Mobile Install Ad was disapproved by Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, mobile, installation, ads

I setup a Mobile App using the developer's panel and added all the correct information as mentioned in the tutorial video on the Facebook SDK page.

It's a native iOS app so I supplied the bundle ID and the App Store ID. I've installed the SDK and Facebook is registering installs whenever I run it on my device.

However once I tried to use the "Promote" feature to setup install ads it keeps getting rejected by Facebook on the grounds that the URL is bad. The URL works fine as I've tested it multiple times. The URL is generated by Facebook itself using the App ID.

I've tried submitting it again after changing the creative, but I'm assuming I've been blacklisted since it immediately is disapproved.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried contacting them?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app limited to a certain region or country? 
My ad was also disapproved and this is what I got:

"The destination URL of this ad violates our Ad Guidelines or could not be reviewed. Please check the URL you have submitted to ensure that it is free of any spelling errors and that it complies with our Advertising Guidelines. Please note that all sites must be viewable and functioning properly, regardless of the viewer's location. Additionally, sites are prohibited from linking to proprietary file types (.pdf, .doc, etc,) initiating automatic downloads, or trapping a user's browser in any way (e.g., pop-ups of any kind).
"

In my case the only logical explanation would be the availability of the app, as it is only available in one country. I link directly to the app store so that should not be a problem...

Sorry for my reply, i know it's not very helpful, but there is so little info on the web about it. I need to do detective work in order to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same thing. I think Facebook changed a ton of stuff in their ads dashboard. I created a new ad yesterday and it was finally approved. Try again.